# Android Market masked e-mail lifetime

Tags: android, google-play, google-checkout

When people buy apps on Android Market, Google does not, by default, disclose their e-mail addresses to the seller; instead, the seller gets a masked address along the lines of `LASTNAME-btv3b3e5dml@checkout.google.com`, which forwards mail to the real recipient. Does anyone know if these aliases ever expire? If so, what's the lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have a built-in expiration date, but the address can be disabled any time the buyer indicates s/he no longer wants to receive emails from a particular vendor - It's a function of Google Checkout (hence the subdomain).

From [Google Checkout's Privacy Policy Page](https://checkout.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=39332) -

> At your request, Google will keep your email address confidential on
>   an order-by-order basis. This is accomplished by creating an anonymous
>   email forwarding address which you may disable at any time. When
>   placing your order, select keep your email address private and Google
>   will then forward the seller's emails to you without sharing your real
>   email address.
>
> If you no longer want to receive emails from a seller, simply click
>   the 'Stop receiving emails from...' opt-out link at the bottom of any
>   email from that seller. You may be prompted to sign into your account
>   before confirming your selection. If you later contact the seller,
>   email forwarding will automatically be re-enabled to allow the seller
>   to respond to your inquiry.